# Gmail API does not support new thread Ids?

Tags: gmail-api

Conversations / threads have different Ids in [old](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKlpa.png) and [new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3swcC.png) UIs, but it looks that [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/) works only with [old Ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whZ5k.png)?

If so, is it possible to get old conversation / thread id from new and vice versa?

Or Google is going to release Gmail API v2 sometime?

I tried to use [gmail-compose-encoder.js](https://gist.github.com/danrouse/52212f0de2fbfe33cfc56583f20ccb74). It is possible to decode `FMfcgxvzLhhSPCtzSXwHlfFgGQtTjVKn` to `thread-f:1617567580158230396` and then convert number part to hex and you get `1672c124d784ff7c`, which is correct answer.
But what about `LXphbRLrghxkrJpTdcKgWlWJwXwczvLXzkKNrRlBxxB`, which decodes to `thread-a:mmiai-r7943408968338036837`? How can I convert this to `167084ad8beabc6b`?

I did some Gmail app debugging and found that this new and legacy thread ids mapping is performed in the back-end, which means that probably there is some persistence layer involved.

Answer (score 2):

In the new Gmail version, the id available in the address bar is an encoded value. You can get the thread id from the HTML. Try searching "data-legacy-thread-id" in the HTML elements.

Or you can find it by running JavaScript code in the console:

```
document.querySelector('[data-legacy-thread-id]').getAttribute('data-legacy-thread-id')
```